New a. Peperomia turning black
I’d like to ask if anyone knows how to help a plant when its inner leaves are turning black. It’s fairly new, I repotted as soon as I got it because it had bad soil, I used a mix of the old soil, orchid bark and pearlite.
Its was one big plant so I split it at the base into two. I keep it by the window but I dont think its sunburn because it hasnt been sunny much here. The leaves are not crunchy at all just kind of flimsy
Please help I cant find any info on the internet of my exact problem.

Can you add a photo or two for us?

Old soil? Orchid bark? Keeping a succulent wet much?
